# How to deploy resource groups or azure resources from one subscription to another via Azure DevOps

Tags: azure

Is there a way to deploy resource group or resources from one subscription to another.

I have already tested the move function in Azure but I really want to copy the elements then paste them into another subscription. (with Azure DevOps)

Does anyone have a solution ?

Thanks in Advance,

Charline

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Azure DevOps and the subscription is in the same subscription as your DevOps environment you can create a new release pipeline and push the template.  If the Azure subscription is different you can create a [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) to it and use it in the release pipeline that way.

Comment: Hi @Narthring
Thank you for your answer, 
Can you explain to me how to create the release, what I have to configure?

Comment: Microsoft has a good walkthrough here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines